# Visual Studio 2010 project won't debug - Error 14Unable to cast object of type 'ItemTypes' to type 'System.String'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-3.5, itemscontrol

I am helping another developer with his .net application and he told me when he installed visual studio 2012 on his machine it messed up his vs2010 application. When I try to debug or build my website which is web forms .net 3.5 I get these errors:

```
Error   14  Unable to cast object of type 'ItemTypes' to type 'System.String'.  C:\Projects\Solutions\PAB3\Pab3 V2\MediaPoint\MPOwnMedia.aspx   1

Error   51  Unable to cast object of type 'ItemTypes' to type 'System.String'.  C:\Projects\Solutions\PAB3\Pab3\MediaPoint\MPPosition.aspx  1
```

I have a blue squiggly here:

[image]

If I hide this file from the project another one of these errors appear.

I am using visual studio 2010 to run this .net web forms application and I have vs2012 installed as well. There are ItemTypes in the code behind.

Has any one experienced this problem before because it seems quite obscure?

Comment: Can you recheck the build version of the framework for the project ?

Comment: @kh_s I rechecked and its .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

If its an environment issue. You can reset to the default using 
Devenv /ResetSettings SettingsFile

MSDN Link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273(v=vs.90).aspx

Hope it works..

Comment: I tried your suggestion by running the Visual Studio command prompt for 2010 first changed directory to this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE. Then I ran this command: Devenv.exe /ResetSettings "C:/Users/nickgowdy/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Settings/CurrentSettings.vssettings". It didn't work :(

Comment: :( Are you looking into the option it may not be an environment issue